# How to change the number of builds kept by Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build

How can one set the number of builds kept by Jenkins for a specific job?

Jenkins keeps the last 30 builds of all our jobs. For a specific job, though, we would like to keep 60 builds, not 30.

I went to the job's configuration page, ticked "Discard old builds", entered "60" into "Max # of builds to keep", saved the job configuration, and restarted Jenkins.

After this change, Jenkins still keeps only 30 builds of the job. What am I doing wrong?

Related question: Why are only 30 builds kept? (I thought the default was not to delete any builds.)

We use Jenkins version 2.164.1 under Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The UI is limited to 30 builds. Try accessing older builds via the url with the build number, f.e.

```
https://myjenkins.uk/view/TWIN/job/myjob/insert-build-number-here/
```

You can also access the builds with stored artifacts on your jenkins master, f.e.:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myjob/builds
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that you are right, but you are! I can't think of a more misleading UI right now. Speechless.

Comment: There is now a (very difficult to discover) UI to go backwards to older builds - hover over the build list and a tiny navigator will appear at the top right of the list.

Answer (score 29):

By default Jenkins keeps all builds in its disk and its advised that you use build discard to remove older builds to save disk space. This is a feature that is given to you by Jenkins so you can change the number of builds you want to keep.

If you are using a freestyle job change the max build as seen in the below screen shot
[image: FreeStyleJenkinsJob]
If you are using a Declarative pipeline you can just add this to your code:

```
pipeline {
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30', artifactNumToKeepStr: '30'))
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: where can we find that screen?

Comment: create a freestyle job and click on the Discard old Builds checkbox