# How to change the number of builds to keep for all the projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to change the number of builds to keep for all the projects in Jenkins.

What I have tried is Discard old builds and strategy log rotate for individual projects.
[image]

It tried this too but it is applicable to a single project only. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145735/how-to-change-the-number-of-builds-kept-by-jenkins)

In my Jenkins, there are multiple projects and I am applying this solution by configuring individual projects. 
Is there is any way by which strategy can be applied to all the projects by applying a single configuration?

Comment: As of Jenkins 2.221, build discarders can be configured globally. This is not in LTS release yet. In the meantime, you may look for plugins like Configuration Slicing. Another solution could be system groovy script. You can access all job configuration programmatically.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks. It is on weekly release now. Do you have any idea on how to use this feature? An example will help the most.

Comment: Sorry I haven't used it yet.